# Show/hide button based on state React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

I have a button called download, it is a component. The functionality is written in a container.

I want the button to be hidden as default, unless the "(i === number)" condition is true in the download function.

However, it is tricky, since this condition will only be validated when I click "download". I am not sure how do I validate this logic beforehand to determine if the button needs to be displayed or not.

Can you please help? I am trying to set a state for showing button, but it doesn't work.

My code basically looks like this -

container:

```
state = {
  showButton: false,
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.download();
};

download = async () => {
  const data = await this.props.client
      .query({
          query: numberQuery,
          fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      })
  // retrive data from number query ....
  const contentData = data.data.content;
 
  // retrieve and format numbers
  const numbers = this.getNumbers(contentData);
 
  // call get number and get the individual number here
  const number = await this.getNumber();
 
  numbers.forEach((i) => {
     // this is to check if numbers contain the number from getNumber(), if 
     // number matches number in numbers
     if (i === number) {
       this.setState({
        showButton: true,
       });
          // call functions, start downloading
     };
   });
  };
 
 render() {
   return (
     {this.state.showButton ? 
      <Download 
      onStartDownload={() => this.download()}
      /> : null}
    );
 };
```

component:

```
 class Download extends Component {
  state = {
    startDownload: false,
  };
 
  startDownload = () => {
    this.props.onStartDownload();
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Button
          id="download"
          onClick={this.startDownload}
        >
          Download
        </Button>
      </Fragment>
     );
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that the numbers are fetched (and, in turn, the logic for showing/hiding the button is run) only after the download button was clicked, but you want it to run as soon as possible (that is, on the component's mount).

Generally, the fetching of data in React is separated from the render/event handler logic. In your case, a solution is to fetch the data when the component mounts, save it  in state (such as a `numbers` and `number` fields), then, when rendering, check if `number` is in the `numbers` array.

For example:

```
// Container component; child component remains the same

state = {
  number: null,
  numbers: []
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchNumbers();
  this.fetchNumber();
};

async fetchNumbers() {
  const data = await this.props.client
  .query({
      query: numberQuery,
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });
  // retrive data from number query ....
  const contentData = data.data.content;

  // retrieve and format numbers
  const numbers = this.getNumbers(contentData);

  this.setState({ numbers });
}

async fetchNumber() {
  // Assuming this is another HTTP request or something similar
  const number = await this.getNumber();

  this.setState({ number });
}

download = async () => {
  // *only* downloading logic
};
 
 render() {
    const { number, numbers } = this.state;
    const showDownload = numbers.includes(number);

    return showDownload 
        ? <Download onStartDownload={() => this.download()}/> 
        : null;
 };
}
```

Notes:

- Using `Array.includes()` instead of an `Array.forEach()` loop simplifies the code (and will probably save you some bugs in the future!)
- I separated `fetchNumbers()`, which fetches `this.state.numbers`, from `fetchNumber()`, which fetches `this.state.number`, simply because they seem like two separate pieces of state (and therefore fetching them independently is most efficient); you could improve it even further by having the two functions return the data (instead of changing the state), then using `Promise.all()` in `componentDidMount()` (I left it out for simplicity's sake).
- Generally in web dev, a best practice when fetching core data asynchronously is to indicate that the component is not loaded until the data arrives (using a loader, for example). For practice or prototypes it might not be your top priority, but keep that in mind for production.

Comment: Thank you! You are saying, instead of checking numbers.forEach for (i === number), I use includes(). I understand that. However, I do have this piece of logic in the download function:
const locate = numbers.indexOf(number); // locate the index of number in numbers array.
Then in if (i === number) condition, I have:
const content= this.transformArray(contentData[locate]); // to only transform array/download the data of that index in numbers array

How could I apply this logic to download function if I move the rest to fetchNumbers() ? Since contentData is out there too
Thank you

Comment: @soso1234 I'm not sure I understand exactly what you said you need to do in the `download()` function, but you should be able to use `this.state.numbers` and `this.state.number` instead of `numbers` and `number`, and the result should be practically the same. As for `contentData`, if you need to use it in `download()` or anywhere else, storing it in the component's state might help (just like you did with `numbers`!) does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, something like this? -
`state = {
  contentData: [],
};

async fetchContent() {
  const data = await this.props.client
     .query({
        query: numberQuery,
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      })

   // same code
   const contentData = data.data.content;
   this.setState({ contentData });
}`

And wherever I need this data, I just call `this.state.contentData`, correct?
I tried it, and I console log `this.state.contentData`, It seems like nothing is inside.

Comment: This seems good. One suggestion is that in your original code you derived `numbers` from `contentData`, so you could do the same in `fetchContent()` and save an HTTP request. As for debugging, maybe try to log a message when receiving a response in `fetchContent()`? it might help you to pinpoint the origin of the bug

Comment: I tried that the showdownload always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

you need a constructor in your class component and to update the state you need to use `setState()`,
review the code to follow
:

```
 class Download extends react.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();// required
    this.state = {
      startDownload: false
    };
  }

  startDownload = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      // I use prevState, to bring the previous state value
      startDownload: !prevState.startDownload // here the value is inverted
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <> // this is equivalent to the fragment
        <button id="download" onClick={this.startDownload}>
          Download
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would this code behave any differently to OPs current code? The state is defined as a class field, which doesn't need to be explicitly inside of a `constructor()`